# Back and forward buttons to handle webview?

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-button

How do I make my two buttons to handle back and forward pages in webview?

edit: I try to make two buttons to handle my webview. Like the first one take you the previous page and the second one take you to next page (if possible). I try to make them work like computer browser's back and forward buttons.

Thank you
-Eljas

Comment: Your question is incomplete. Please add more detailed info what are you trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
webview.goBack();
webview.goForward();
```